# Convert BGR channels apart from (1,1,1) and (0,0,0) to white (255,255,255)

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a input [image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajinkya933/Extracting-text-from-images-using-Google-Vision/master/3.png) from which I have to convert all BGR channels which do not belong to [0,0,0] and [1,1,1] to white [255,255,255].

I made a code which can convert all channels except [0,0,0]
to white.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

for i in range (1,5):
    im = cv2.imread(str(i)+'.png')
    im[np.any(im != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)] = [255,255,255]
    cv2.imwrite('a'+str(i)+'.png', im)
```

My aim is to convert all channels except [0,0,0] and [1,1,1] to white.To do that I made following changes to the code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

for i in range (1,5):
    im = cv2.imread(str(i)+'.png')
    im[np.any(im != [0, 0, 0] & im != [1,1,1], axis=-1)] = [255,255,255]
    cv2.imwrite('a'+str(i)+'.png', im)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 6, in <module>
    im[np.any(im != [0, 0, 0] & im != [1,1,1], axis=-1)] = [255,255,255]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How to convert all image to white [255,255,255] except [0,0,0] and [1,1,1] pixels by changing the above code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

`&` has higher precedence than `==` and `!=`, so you need parentheses to make this work:

```
 im[np.any((im != [0, 0, 0]) & (im != [1, 1, 1]), axis=-1)] = [255, 255, 255]
```